# Codeigniter - use two like and where together

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have a problem with use two like statement and where together:

```
    $this->db->select('something');
    $this->db->where('WHERE',$var);
    $this->db->where_in('WHEREIN', $var);
    $this->db->like('LIKE1',$query);
    $this->db->or_like('LIKE2',$query);
    $query = $this->db->get('table');
```

My query must select `LIKE1` or `LIKE2` where `WHERE` and`WHEREIN` is true.

If I use `or_like`, `where` statement get `or` too,

If i use just `like`, it's become `like AND like` statement

Any solution??

Comment: What is the statement you want to create? And what is the statement that is actually created by Codeigniter? You can find this by `echo`ing `$this->db->last_query();`

Comment: SELECT `*`
FROM `pic`
WHERE `doc` = '123456'
AND `place` IN('1,2,3')
AND  `name` LIKE '%query%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `code` LIKE '%query%' ESCAPE '!'
ORDER BY `id` DESC

Comment: I want something like this: where `doc` AND where `place` AND ( like `code` OR like `name`)

Comment: SELECT * FROM pic WHERE doc = '123456' AND place IN('1,2,3') AND name (LIKE '%query%' ESCAPE '!' OR code LIKE '%query%' ESCAPE '!' ) ORDER BY id DESC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this solution:

use `group_start()` and `group_end()`, so my code turn to

```
$this->db->select('something');
$this->db->where('WHERE',$var);
$this->db->where_in('WHEREIN', $var);
$this->db->group_start();
$this->db->like('LIKE1',$query);
$this->db->or_like('LIKE2',$query);
$this->db->group_end();
$query = $this->db->get('table');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a complex where clause, you can write it this way:

```
$this->db->where("doc = '123456' AND place IN('1,2,3') AND name (LIKE '%query%' ESCAPE '!' OR code LIKE '%query%' ESCAPE '!' )", NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run this kind of query is better if you create a model like this:

```
function example(){

    $query = "( SQL QUERY )";
    $search = $this->db->query($query);
    return $search->result_array(); 
}
```

Comment: For security reason, I don't want use `$this->db->query()` function.

Comment: what you think if you use  $data = $this->security->xss_clean($data); when you send the data to the model to prevent xss on the query?